# $g \in O(f) \Rightarrow f \in O(g)$?

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

> Assume $f,g: \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb R $ are two functions such that $f \in \Theta(n^k)$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$ and $g \in O(f)$. Does this imply $f \in O(g)$?

We know that

$$f \in \Theta(n^k) \Rightarrow f \in O(n^k).$$

Since $g \in O(f)$, we are allowed to assume that

$$g(n) \le c \cdot f(n)$$

for some $n \in \Bbb N$ and $c > 0$. I feel like the statement can't be true, but I can't tell why. Does anyone have a hint for me?

Comment: Do an example.  As $n \to \infty$, we have $n^2 = O(n^3)$ but not $n^3 = O(n^2)$.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x$ looks like a counter-example.

Comment: But the excercise states that the condition holds for "some $k \in \Bbb N$". Giving a counter-example doesn't contradict the statement, it only shows that it's not true in general.

Comment: So there might be some $k \in \Bbb N$ where it does hold indeed.

Comment: How about: $n^{k-1} = O(n^k)$ but not $n^k = O(n^{k-1})$

Comment: But it isn't said that $g \in O(n^{k-1})$.

Answer (score 1):

> We show the assumption is not true by providing a counter example. This is sufficient to answer the problem since it shows that $f\in O(g)$ does *not* always necessarily follow.
>
> We consider $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(n)=n^k$ and $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, g(n)=n^{k-1}$.

At first we show that $f$ and $g$ fulfill the conditions stated in the assumption.

> In order to show 
>   \begin{align*}
> f\in\Theta(n^k)\qquad\qquad\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>    we have to find constants $c_1,c_2>0$ with 
>   \begin{align*}
> c_1 n^k<f(n)<c_2 n^k\qquad\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Note that we consider in (2) the complete domain $\mathbb{N}$, since there is no side-condition given on $n$.
>   We take $c_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $c_2=2$ and we obtain with $f(n)=n^k$
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2} n^k<n^k<2 n^k\qquad\qquad  \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
> \end{align*}
>   and (1) follows.

In order to show that $g\in O(f)$ we have to find a constant $C>0$ so that
\begin{align*}
|g(n)|<C |f(n)|\qquad\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{align*}
Taking $C=2$ does the job, since
\begin{align*}
n^{k-1}<2n^k\qquad\qquad\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{align*}

> **Conclusion:** Given $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(n)=n^k$ and $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, g(n)=n^{k-1}$, we have $f\in\Theta(n^k)$, $g\in O(f)$, but this does not imply $f\in O(g)$, since
>   \begin{align*}
> n^{k}\not\in O(n^{k-1})\qquad\qquad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
> \end{align*}